# Troubleshooting Apache Tomcat and Next.js Integration for Subpages

Tags: javascript, typescript, tomcat, next.js, server

I've recently set up an Apache Tomcat server locally and deployed a Next.js web app. In my Next.js project's next.config.js file, I have the following code snippet:

```js
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
}
```

This configuration is used to export the project to the "out" directory, making it a static resource. When I zip the contents of the "out" directory and rename it to a .war file, the project runs smoothly.

However, I've encountered an issue when trying to access subpages, like localhost:port/webapp/example?id=1. The server returns a 404 error, and I suspect that this is because the pages in the "out" directory are not organized into separate folders for subpages.

What can I do to resolve my problem? Has it something to do with URL rewriting?

Kind Regards